# Issue with Swashbuckle and MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, mediatypeformatter

I am trying to apply Swashbuckle on my WebApi. In most cases it works.

For some Api endpoints, for `GET`, the methods accept `JSON` from query string as argument. For translating the data from `JSON` to .NET objects, there are some `MediaTypeFormatter` at place. The `MediaTypeFormatter`s generally look like below:

```
public class MyMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof (MyType);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Do deserialization here
    }
}
```

My WebApi works when invoked from my WebApp as well as from Postman. However, when I invoke the same service from Swagger-UI, it breaks, and complaints about:

```
{
  "Message": "The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'MyType' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

Do I need to specify any explicit configuration for this?

Comment: From what I see, I guess Swashbuckle interprets the parameter as an body parameter instead of a query parameter. Can you share one of the `GET` methods?

Comment: @venerik Thank you for your comment. I don't have access to my system right now. Thus, it is difficult to share the `GET` requests. However, the method argument is a comparatively complex object  graph, for example, an object containing arrays of different types of object and so on.